# Android locale gets changed when the orientation is changed to landscape

Tags: android, orientation, locale

I am creating an android application in which i have set the locale for english and tamil language when i click the tamil language it displays the strings in tamils and every thing works fine.I am having an activity which is in landscape mode when the start that activity the locale gets changed from tamil to english even i have used

```
   android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

in manifest but it didn't works.

Can anyone tell me how i can overcome this issue.I have store the language in shared preference.

```
 private static MyApplication mInstance;
public static final String PREF_NAME = "CoconutMetaData";
public static final String PREF_USER_LANGUAGE_KEY = "userLanguage";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myLanguage = preferences.getString(PREF_USER_LANGUAGE_KEY,"en");

    // Set user specific locale (Language)
    Locale mLocale = new Locale(myLanguage);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        conf.setLocale(mLocale);
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    /**
     * To display overflow menu when hard menu key is pressed (for devices that have hard menu key)
     */
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
    ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `Local` and `Configuration` object globally

```
    Locale mLocale;
    Configuration conf;
```

and set Local from

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    try {
         conf.setLocale(mLocale);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

try following code, this is good way to set local language

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

[Example](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-at-runtime/)